# How to add a Database Server in Catalog?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, oracle-dbms, arccatalog

I have ArcSDE on an Oracle database and I want to add a database server connection to ArcCatalog, I've seen several sites but they don't say what I have to write down. Let me explain:

From the tree at the left I have several options, from hard drives, database connections to database servers and gis servers. When I right clic the Database servers option and choose add database server I get a dialog box asking me for a Database Server, so, what is what I have to write there?

I've tried with:

- servername\user
- servername\oracle11g
- servername\ESRI_sde

Thanks.

And SDE Administration

Answer (score 3):

Using Spatial Database Connection in ArcCatalog

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Making_an_ArcSDE_service_connection_from_ArcGIS_Desktop_to_a_geodatabase_in_Oracle/002n0000008n000000/

Comment: Thanks mappers, but we already got this down, what we want is to add a database server so we can administer ArcSDE (user permissions, etc.). Also, we have ArcGis 9.3.1

Comment: then you need SDE Admin http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/Support_files/admincmdref.htm

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/Support_files/admincmdref.htm) is the 9.3.1 help for most everything you need.
The connection depends a bit on the method you are using in oracle for connections.
I normally used sid name (easiest to maintain).